# Getting "Error: Server Error" when I go to "Datastore Admin" in GAE UI

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I need to delete all data in my datastore.  I believe this is possible from the "Datastore Admin" page of the admin UI, however when I visit this page I get the following error:

```
Error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.
```

There is no additional information that I can see.  Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Comment: Are you still getting this error?  If not, how was this issue resolved?  Feel free to post a self-answer to consider this question resolved if that's the case.